# namedCache to Localcahce infinispan-config-12.1.xsd

Tags: mongodb, wildfly, infinispan

I have configuration something like this when to try to upgrade to the 12.1 version getting error,

> Check that your configuration is up-to date for Infinispan
> '12.1.4.Final' and if you have the proper dependency in the classpath:
> org.infinispan.commons.CacheConfigurationException: ISPN000327: Cannot
> find a parser for element 'named-cache' in namespace
> 'urn:infinispan:config:12.1'.

I could not find the replacement for the below config, please input your suggestion.

```
<infinispan
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="urn:infinispan:config:5.1 http://www.infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-5.1.xsd"
        xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:5.1">

    <namedCache name="test-cache">
        <eviction strategy="LIRS" maxEntries="1000"/>
        <expiration lifespan="5400000" maxIdle="4400000"/>
    </namedCache>
</infinispan>
```

This is the current version I am trying to upgrade.

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
        <artifactId>infinispan-core</artifactId>
         <version>12.1.7.Final</version
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/titles/configuring/configuring.html#declarative-configuring) suggests this:

```
<infinispan>
   <cache-container>
      <!-- Configures a local cache. -->
      <local-cache name="local"/>
   </cache-container>
</infinispan>
```

This would give you a local cache, analogous elements exist for `replicated-cache`, `distributed-cache`. etc. Eviction nowadays seems to be handled by the memory element, with `REMOVE` replacing the long-deprecated (now gone) strategies like `LIRS`, etc. (not clue why or if a more fine-grained control over the strategy is still possible), see [Eviction](https://infinispan.org/docs/12.1.x/titles/configuring/configuring.html#eviction-config) in the documentation:

```
<local-cache name="maximum_count">
  <encoding media-type="application/x-protostream"/>
  <memory max-count="500" when-full="REMOVE"/>
</local-cache>
```

[Expiration](https://infinispan.org/docs/12.1.x/titles/configuring/configuring.html#expiration-config) still works like before, it seems.

While xsd schemas tend to be pretty hard to read, the [one](https://infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-12.1.xsd) for this xml is at least not horribly complicated but mostly straight-forward.

Comment: is mostly correct, but to follow the latest schema, use the following:

    <local-cache name="test-cache">
        <expiration lifespan="5400000" max-idle="4400000"/>
            <memory>
                <binary eviction="COUNT" size="1000" strategy="REMOVE"/>
            </memory>
    </local-cache>

Comment: The binary element seems to be deprecated since 11.0, at least that's what the XSD says: `Deprecated since 11.0. Use instead the 'encoding' element to specify the media type of keys and values, plus the storage attribute as 'HEAP'. Store keys and values as bytes in the Java heap. Cache entries are serialized to binary representations. Note that binary storage violates object equality. This occurs because equality is determined by the equivalence of the resulting byte[] instead of the object instances. `